# Differences between schdule calling a c# console application using windows tasks schedule or using quartz

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I have developed a c# console application, which implement a long running process (last around 30-40 minutes to complete). 
Now I want to create a simple GUI inside my asp.net mvc web application, which allows users to set a schedule when to run this console application.
So not sure which approach I should consider to implement this, if we consider these 2 general requirements:-

1. Calling c# console application.
2. Ability to create view inside my ap.net mvc web application , which allow users to manage the schedule settings?

So what are the advantages and disadvantages of these 2 approaches?

1. Using third part tools such as quartz to schedule the console application execution ?
2. Or to use the windows tasks scheduler (we are using windows service 2012 R2)?

Thanks

Comment: This article, [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) is a good starting point. It lists some possibilities to doing this including Quartz. It also highlights some of the pitfalls to watch for when implementing your chosen solution.

Comment: @Igor thanks for the link, i already read it .. but this link is talking about running these tasks using web based schedulers , and is not mentioning using windows task scheduler. or comparing between the 2 approaches (which is my question here).. now in case of using web based scheduler , i need to keep my application pool alive, for example by calling the homepage each 5 minutes, otherwise if i define a background job to run during non-business hours where no activity is made on the system,, then these scheduler will not be able to call the related console applications

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of the first approach is that you are not dependent on Windows specific features and can hope one day to be able to port your code under the Core CLR and run it on other platforms (like Linux for example). Obviously if you go with the first approach you should not be putting Quarz in your ASP.NET MVC application but rather have a separate Windows Service. The reason for that is because long running threads is definitely something you don't want in a web application because you don't have any control over when the AppPool could be recycled.

On the other hand the second approach with the Windows task scheduler could be easier to implement in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. now i do not want to put my long running logic inside asp.net MVC, as i mentioned this long running process is implemented as c# console application,, which will run outside iis ,, either i go with windows task scheduler approach or using quartz approach is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, using Quarz is alright, but not inside your ASP.NET application. It should be placed in a separate Windows Service. Make sure that Quarz is not hosted under IIS because when IIS recycles your AppDomain it will kill Quarz and everything you might have scheduled. So basically you will need to host Quarz in a separate container and communicate with this container from within your ASP.NET application.

Comment: Yes I will not run the long running process inside IIS .. as IIS is not designed to handle long running process, and IIS application pools might shut down causing my long running process to ends unexpectedly .. second point why you say to have it as windows service,, as i find that my long running process (which mainly do a network scan to get info about our servers and VMS and update our ERP system) is best implemented as c# console app, rather than being a windows service.

Comment: OK great, so you get the point. Just don't forget that the same way you shouldn't run your long running process in IIS, you shouldn't run the scheduler (Quartz) in IIS.

Comment: But the only point i have is that I only use windows task scheduler to do admin tasks , such as backup our database every week, backup certain folders at the end of each day, etc.. but i have never use WTS to do business functions such as the long running process i am asking about,,, so i have a feeling that using windows task scheduler to do a non-admin tasks will have some drawbacks,, as it will create dependence on my application out side IIS,, also it will require windows OS to run (although currently my asp.net mvc can not run under non-windows OS).. so not sure about it ..

Comment: i did not use quartz before,, but from my reading that it can run outside IIS,, is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, your understanding about Quartz is correct - it can perfectly fine run outside IIS. For example it can run in a Windows Service application.

Comment: ok i got your point, so you mean i i need to install quartz as windows service rather than being running under iis, in case it runs as windows service , it will keep running on the background as long as the operating system is running,and no recyle will be done, is this correct ? Second question,let say that quartz runs under IIS , and it calls a console app, then the console app start execution, and during the console application execution the application pool recycled ,, so i do no think this will interrupt the console application execution?? is this correct ?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between these mechanisms is that Windows Tasks Scheduler runs continuously as internal component of Windows while Quartz is a library which allows to run scheduler inside your application domain. It means that when you are using Quartz, scheduler is depended on application pool recycling.

In other words, Windows Tasks Scheduler is more stable, but Quartz is more flexible to use. I recommend you to use Quartz, but pay additional attention to application pool settings (idle timeout) to avoid unexpected scheduler stop.

Comment: i did not use quartz before,, but from my reading it will be running outside IIS ?? is this correct ?

Comment: There are nothing terrible to host you scheduler in your web application. You just need to keep in mind that scheduler will be restarted at the same time as application pool. It I not a big problem. You can set idle timeout for application pool in 0, to avoid app.pool recycling. Or you can ping home page of your application every minute to ensure that it is run. In this case your scheduler will be restarted only on manual IIS restart and it is absolutely correct.

Comment: so u are saying that it is not wrong to have the web scheduler itself running under iis,but it is wrong to have the long running process runs under iis , so in this case I can have my Schduler (hangfire or Quartz)runs under iis which will call the long running console app ,, is this correct??

Comment: second question, i did not understand your point which is "You just need to keep in mind that scheduler will be restarted at the same time as application pool..... "; now let say that quartz calls a console application, then the console application start execution,, and during the console application execution the application pool recycled ,, so i do no think this will interrupt the console application execution?? is this correct ?so why i need to worry about application pool recycle ..

Comment: Your scheduler will be hosted in IIS, not the console application. So, if console app is run by scheduler , it will be completed independently from application pool. In other words, your console app will be run  periodically by scheduler while web application works. When console application is already run, it will not be stopped despite of application pool recycling.